# Setting relative height for Grid children

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

I'm adding 2 children to a Grid like this:

```
    private void pInitStackLayout()
    {
        grid1 = new Grid()
        {
        };

        grid2 = new Grid()
        {
        };

        biggrid = new Grid()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        };
        biggrid.Children.Add(grid1,0,0);
        biggrid.Children.Add(grid2,0,1);

        this.Content = biggrid;
    }
```

The ContentPage's (which is a Navigation Page) Content is the biggrid.

I would like to make it so that grid1 takes up 80% of the available height, and grid2 takes up 20% (or the rest).

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the RowDefinitions Height on the biggrid? For example `biggrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple actually, just set the RowDefinitions of `biggrid`.

```
// RowDefinitions isolated

RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
{
    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) },
    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
}

// RowDefinitions isolated

// Actual code
private void pInitStackLayout()
{
    grid1 = new Grid()
    {
    };

    grid2 = new Grid()
    {
    };

    biggrid = new Grid()
    {
        RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
        {
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
        },

        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        Margin = new Thickness(0),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    };
    biggrid.Children.Add(grid1,0,0);
    biggrid.Children.Add(grid2,0,1);

    this.Content = biggrid;
}
```